# Orders belongs to custom created order status is not showing in my account recent orders?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, order-status

I created a custom order status like below.

**config.xml**

```
<sales>
    <order>
        <statuses>
          <backorders translate="label">
            <label>Back Orders</label>
          </backorders>
        </statuses>
        <states>
          <backorders translate="label">
            <label>Back Orders</label>
            <statuses>
              <backorders default="1"/>
            </statuses>
          </backorders>
        </states>
   </order>
</sales>
```

**mysql script**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
// Required tables
$statusTable = $installer->getTable('sales/order_status');
$statusStateTable = $installer->getTable('sales/order_status_state');

// Insert statuses
$installer->getConnection()->insertArray(
    $statusTable,
    array('status', 'label'),
    array(
        array(
            'status' => 'backorders', 
            'label' => 'Back Order'
        )
    )
);

// Insert states and mapping of statuses to states
$installer->getConnection()->insertArray(
    $statusStateTable,
    array('status', 'state', 'is_default'),
        array(
            array(
                'status' => 'backorders', 
                'state' => 'backorders', 
                'is_default' => 1
            )
        )
    );
$installer->endSetup();
```

During the back order the order status is saved to backorders and it will show in the admin panel order list.
My question is the same order is not showing in the customers my account recent orders section.

**Why this orders under status of backorders not showing in recent orders page?**

In  the admin panel if we create an invoice the order status is changed to ***Processing***, but if i create an invoice for the orders wich belongs to **backorders** are not changed to **Processing**.But if i completed the shipping for **backorders** order it will change the order status to **Completed**

What is the issue causing this?

**UPDATE : This is how i update the order status in the observer**

```
$order->setData('state', 'backorders');
$order->setStatus('backorders');
$history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);                 
$history->setStatus('backorders')->setData('state', 'backorders')->setIsCustomerNotified(false);               
$order->save();
```

**system->Order Statuses Screen**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after creating programatically invoice you have to set **state** and **status** for that

```
$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
$order->setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
$order->setStatus(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
$history = $invoice->getOrder()->addStatusHistoryComment(
    'created invoice', true
);
$invoice->sendEmail(false, '');              
$order->save();
```

second solution

you use the default magento `state` with custom `status` that will solved you problem.

Comment: Thank you.Here i am not creating invoice pragmatically.I created the invoice from the admin panel only. and why it is not showing in my account area too?

Comment: @Qaisar.I cannot understand what u r telling.Can you please update your answer

Comment: @mujas i am trying to there is `backorders` attach with `backorders` as you can see in admin panel > system > order statuses you can assign state to status their only check that

Comment: it's showing, I updated the question with the image

Comment: @mujas i think you are talking about this question i update my solution here too

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution for that:

you need go to this File Path : app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Order/History.php

and comment of this code

```
->addFieldToFilter('state', array('in' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getVisibleOnFrontStates()))
```

It will be work.

Thanks !